# Change selected segment of UISegmentedControl

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6

I have a `UISegmentedControl` in my `ModeViewController`

**ModeViewController.h:**

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *Segment;
- (IBAction)switchMode:(id)sender;
```

**ModeViewController.m:**

```
- (IBAction)switchMode:(id)sender {
    //I Tried this way    
    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = (UISegmentedControl *) sender;
    _Segment.selectedSegmentIndex = segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;


//or this way
NSInteger selectedSegment = segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;
[_Segment setSelectedSegmentIndex:selectedSegment];

}
```

But as soon as I change to `ViewController` and come back it will only display the default selected Segment! Any idea?

Comment: That property needs to be `strong`.

Comment: He's using `IBOutlet`, `weak` is fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you change view controller and you come back the viewDidLoad method  called again thats why you are seeing the default selected index. The way to overcome this is store the selected the selected index into some app delegate property or you can create singleton class for the better design  to preserve the state  .And in your viewDidLoadMethod .

```
-viewDidLoad
{
  AppDelegate *delegate=[[UIApplication sharedAppliection]delegate];
  [_Segment setSelectedSegmentIndex:delegate.selectedIndex];
}
```

This wil work for you .

Comment: I have a NSInteger in my AppDelegate and I save the Index in it! every time I go in the ViewDidLoad I set the selectedSegment

Answer (score 2):

**Problem**

The problem here is that whan a Viewcontroller is presented modally the properties inside it has only the lifetime till it is dismissed.

Check your code there will be an instantiation of the viewcontroller  which gives you a new instance and in this new instance the segment control from the nib set value will be shown(or whatever you set in `viewDidload` or `ViewWillAppear` methods

**Solution**

The solution is to store the value somewhere where it is possible to retrive and set in viewDelegates as

```
  [self.segment setSelectedSegmentIndex:storedIndex];
```

For this purpose of storing there are different options

1. Global variable in appDelegate
2. NSUserDefaults
3. CoreData
4. Sqlite
5. Plist
6. TextFile

The easiest one is the first but if you are implementing any of this already a field for this is a considerable option.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make that variable `selectedSegment` global in your app. you can define it in `AppDelegate`

[iPhone, how do I App Delegate variable which can be used like global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833294/iphone-how-do-i-app-delegate-variable-which-can-be-used-like-global-variables)