# Obj-C - Change selected segment control segment programatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to change the selected segmented control when a button is pressed inside my app. However, when I use the following, the segment highlight changes as it should, however the actual case associated with the segment does not. Any idea why this might be?

**ViewController.h**

```
- (IBAction)segmentedControl:(id)sender;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;
```

**ViewController.m**

```
  - (IBAction)closeBubbleOne:(id)sender {

        [self.segmentControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:2];
        NSLog(@"WHAT IS RETURNED %ld", self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex);

    }

    - (IBAction)segmentedControl:(id)sender {

        self.segmentedControl = (UISegmentedControl *) sender;
        NSInteger selectedSegment = self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;

        switch (selectedSegment)
            {  
                case 0:

                   [self.sidetableView setHidden:YES];
                   [self.neighboursView setHidden:NO];
                   [self.friendsView setHidden:YES];

                   self.pullDown.hidden = YES;
                   self.arrowDown.hidden = YES;
                   break;


                case 1:

                   self.barhideView.hidden = YES;
                   [self.sidetableView setHidden:YES];
                   [self.friendsView setHidden:NO];
                   [self.neighboursView setHidden:YES];

                   [self reloadAccepted];

                   self.pullDown.hidden = YES;
                   self.arrowDown.hidden = YES;
                   break;


                case 2:

                   self.barhideView.hidden = YES;
                   [self.sidetableView setHidden:NO];
                   [self.neighboursView setHidden:YES];
                   [self.friendsView setHidden:YES];

                   if ([self.myFriendData count] == 0) {
                       self.pullDown.hidden = NO;
                       self.arrowDown.hidden = NO;
                    } else {
                       self.pullDown.hidden = YES;
                       self.arrowDown.hidden = YES;
                    }

                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: `self.segmentController` is probably nil.

Comment: How is this possible? @rmaddy

Comment: Maybe you never set it? It's just a hunch based on the behavior of the code you posted. You first need to verify it is nil or not. Then if so, figure out why.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894322/change-selected-segment-of-uisegmentedcontrol

Comment: You're totally right - fixed that, however now the segment highlight changes, the console logs that it's changed to segment 2, but the screen itself does not change. :/ @rmaddy

Comment: What do you mean by *"now the segment highlight changes"* ... *"but the screen itself does not change"*. That seems like a contradiction.

Comment: For example when my button is tapped, the UISegmentControl shows segment 2 highlighted, as it should. However the view associated with segment 2 does not appear when this happens - it simply stays on the view associated with segment 0. Check out added code - I want case 2 to appear when the segment is programatically selected.

Comment: Why the line `self.segmentedControl = (UISegmentedControl *) sender;`? `self.segmentedControl` should be set once when the view controller loads. You should not be setting it every time the user taps on the control.

Comment: Removed it :) Still doesn't fix the issue though lol :/ @rmaddy

Comment: But did you set `self.segmentedControl` in `viewDidLoad` or wherever you actually create the segmented control?

Comment: Yes - I created segmentedControl property in .h, and connected it on the storyboard via the Connections Inspector. I assume by doing this it doesn't need to be 're-created' in the viewDidLoad? @rmaddy When I tap the different segments they change perfectly; it's just when I'm trying to have a separate button make the change that it gives me the problem.

Comment: Now we are back to the first comment. Is `self.segmentedControl` nil? If so then it isn't connected or it's not actually your outlet. But you've shown nothing in your question related to how it is setup so it's difficult to help. But until you get that property set correctly, your code isn't going to work properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199213/discussion-between-brittany-and-rmaddy).

Answer (score 0):

Try calling

```
[self.segmentedControl sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

after this line

```
[self.segmentControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:2];
```

As far as I know, the setSelectedSegmentIndex will not trigger the valueChanged event. So you have to call it manually